# node x-ray Crawling to another site with multiple data

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I want to scrap website to json, because i need that data from website,
i'm following tutorial : https://github.com/matthewmueller/x-ray
but is just return 1 data, i want return many data like this :

```js
{
    "category": "Fashion",
    "data": [
    {
      "merchant-name": "Centro",
      "imageurl":         "https://m.bnizona.com/files/1aa0dd2a47c06f4e30d8bc304d9ad535.jpg",
      "promo-title": "BNI Shop & Win dengan Kartu Kredit BNI di Centro Dept Store, Parkson Dept Store dan Parkson Gourmetmart",
      "valid-until": "valid until 30 November 2017"
    },
    {
      "merchant-name": "Centro",
      "imageurl": "https://m.bnizona.com/files/1aa0dd2a47c06f4e30d8bc304d9ad535.jpg",
      "promo-title": "BNI Shop & Win dengan Kartu Kredit BNI di Centro Dept Store, Parkson Dept Store dan Parkson Gourmetmart",
      "valid-until": "valid until 30 November 2017"
    }
    ]
  },
```

and here is my code :

```js
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

// read link
x('https://m.bnizona.com/index.php/category/index/promo', '.menu li', [{ //read list from .menu li
  "category":'a',
  // "link":'a@href',
  "data":
  x('a@href', {
    "merchant-name"  : ".merchant-name",
    "imageurl"       : "img@src",
    "promo-title"    : ".promo-title",
    "valid-until"    : ".valid-until" 
  }),
}])(function(err, obj){
  console.log(obj)
})
  // .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  // .limit(90)
  .write('solution.json')
```